# Sort Dictionary swift 3.0

Tags: sorting, dictionary, swift3, unordered-set

At some point of coding, I require to sort dictionary to get ordered data based on the Dictionary's Key.

I tried to get the result by:

```
let sortedDict = dict.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

It results into:

```
let dict = ["a0":1, "a3":2 , "a10":2, "a20":3]
```

Though, desired result:

```
let dict = ["a0":1, "a10":2, "a20":3, "a3":2]
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    for i in 0..<parameters!.count {
        let key = "q\(i)"
        if httpBody.contains(key){
            let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\b\(key)\\b", options: .caseInsensitive)
            httpBody = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: httpBody, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<httpBody.utf16.count), withTemplate: "q")
        }
    }
```

Simple sort function will not work here.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is an unordered collection of data, so you can't create an ordered dictionary.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for replying